# Why b=b+1 when b is a byte won't compile but b+=1 compiles

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        byte b=10;
        //b=b+1; //Illegal
        b+=1;   //Legal
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

I want to know why I'm getting a compilation error if I use `b=b+1`, but on the other hand `b+=1` compiles properly while they seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler didn't "describe the reason" for you?????

Comment: error -> (incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte). But in this case "b+=1" how does compiler do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting question. See [JLS 15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent
>   to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1`
>   is evaluated only once.

So when you are writing `b+=1;`, you are actually casting the result into a `byte`, which is the similar expressing as `(byte)(b+1)` and compiler will know what you are talking about. In contrast, when you use `b=b+1` you are adding two different types and therefore you'll get an `Incompatible Types Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

the Error you get is because of the operations with different data types and that can cause an overflow.

when you do this:

```
byte b = 127;
b=b+1;
```

you generate an overflow, so the solution would be casting the result

```
b=(byte) (b+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because can't convert int to byte

You can try:

> b=(byte) (b+1);

Comment: " b+=1 " in this case how it work?

Comment: b+=1  equal b=(byte) (b+1);